# How to enable visual basic in excel 2010 option programmatically with C# / any batch files

Tags: c#, excel, batch-file

Is there a way to programmatically  enable  visual basic in excel 2010 option. In excel the Macro option is being greyed out. I need to enable it programatically.

Comment: VBA is an optional part of Office that may be not installed. If that is the case, there's nothing you can do apart from launching an Office setup. If that is not the case, you shouldn't be doing anything anyway because macro security is supposed to be controlled by the user, not your program.